# Музыкальный проигрыватель

Tags: c#

Скажите вот я знаю такой проигрыватель в C#.NET

```
using System.Media;
```

Потом это

```
SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer("test.wave");
snd.Play();
```

Но вот беда.... этот плеер может проигрывать только .wave файлы, а для mp3, или для других форматов есть плееры? Нет мне не нужен Windows Media Player...

Comment: стоило мне немного погуглить:

- [http://www.slawutich.pp.ua/csharp/57-playing-mp3-files-csharp.html](http://www.slawutich.pp.ua/csharp/57-playing-mp3-files-csharp.html) 
- [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MP3Example.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MP3Example.aspx)

Comment: Спасибо, я бы и сам гуглил, да инет лимитный.

Comment: Ну ничего себе!! Я думал 3-4 строчки...(если без диалогов), а там целый класс создали! Может есть более просто способ? Мне для игрушки нужно.

Comment: может стоить посмотреть в сторону [XNA](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA)

Answer (score 3):

> Ну ничего себе!! Я думал 3-4 строчки...(если без диалогов), а там целый класс создали! Может есть более просто способ? Мне для игрушки нужно.

Зато этот класс удобный и функциональный. Почему бы тебе не скопировать его себе и не использовать? Как вариант, можно выдрать из него только нужную тебе функциональность. Посмотри метод Play из первой ссылки.

Вообще, MCI не подходит для игр. Он слишком простенький. По-моему, он даже не поддерживает несколько звуков одновременно. Поэтому, тебе придётся поискать звуковой движок для .NET, но его исходный код будет во много раз больше, чем с MCI! Хотя, тебя это не должно волновать.

Comment: Полностью согласен с ответом. А также хочу добавить, что для .NET'а имеется вполне достойный звуковой движок - [NAudio][1]. Плюс в разделе документации есть ознакомительные статьи и примеры.


  [1]: http://naudio.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Добавить в References ссылку на Microsoft.DireсtX и Microsoft.DireсtX.AudioVideoPlayback;

```
var MyPlayer = new Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Audio(@"путь к файлу");
MyPlayer.Play();
```

Comment: Вполне сносный вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Существует также mp3-плеер в .NET, System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer, находящийся в сборке PresentationCore.

```
var player = new MediaPlayer();

player.Open(new Uri(@"путь к .mp3"));
player.Play();
```

Подробнее почитайте на MSDN.